# Heroku error H18 "Server Request Interrupted" sock=backend

Tags: sqlite, flask, heroku

I publish my flask app in Heroku(for free) but I have encountered [H18 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vectq.png) and I dont know how to solve this problem. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The response did not complete: can you show some code (Flask endpoint) to understand what your app does?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.